# insert javascript into php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, insert, datepicker

I use the component datepicker in my php application and I want to affect the value of the datepiker component to an element of a php array like this :

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        $wish = array("id" => $_POST["wishID"], "description" => $_POST["wish"], "due_date" => .datepicker( "getDate" ));
    else
    if (array_key_exists("wishID", $_GET))
        $wish = mysqli_fetch_array(WishDB::getInstance()->get_wish_by_wish_id($_GET["wishID"]));
    else
        $wish = array("id" => "", "description" => "", "due_date" => "");
    ?>
```

but I have an error when I run this page  :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'getDate' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\PhpProject1\editWish.php on line 48
```

and the error points on this row :

```
"due_date" => .datepicker( "getDate" )
```

how I can achieve this
thanks,

Comment: Remove the dot before `.datepicker`

Comment: is `.datepicker( "getDate" )` actually a JavaScript code?

Comment: is `datepicker` a PHP function or is a javascript function ?

Comment: like what you wrote @Zathrus : `.datepicker( "getDate" )` is a javascript code

Comment: @Touki, I removed the dot but no changes

Comment: To pass a JS variable to PHP this will help you

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php

Answer (score 1):

You cannot intermix PHP and JavaScript code the way you tried. They are completely different languages, even processed on different parts of the application (JavaScript is client-side, PHP is server-side).

What you need to do is actually use the `.datepicker( "getDate" )` on your HTML page to populate an element in the same form where `wishID` and `wish` inputs are present (like a hidden input, or even text input) and then sumbit that form along to your PHP script. Then you will be able to do something like:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        $wish = array("id" => $_POST["wishID"], "description" => $_POST["wish"], "due_date" => $_POST['your_date_input_field']);
    else
    if (array_key_exists("wishID", $_GET))
        $wish = mysqli_fetch_array(WishDB::getInstance()->get_wish_by_wish_id($_GET["wishID"]));
    else
        $wish = array("id" => "", "description" => "", "due_date" => "");
?>
```